# Apache-Spark library content

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to run a Java test program using the MLlib library from Apache-Spark.

I downloaded the latest Spark version from their website and followed the O'reilly book "Learning Spark, Lightning-Fast Big Data Analysis" to find useful examples and tips, but when it comes to importing the right libraries, they (and the other tutorials I found googling around) use classes that are not included in the Spark folder I downloaded.

Here is an example :

Most of the tutorials import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint, which does not exist in my case. I only have :

- JavaLassoSuite
- JavaLinearRegressionSuite
- JavaRidgeRegressionSuite

I have the same problem with every other files supposed to be included in the library. I tried to download older versions but it is still the same, even with the files which are not directly related to MLlib (org.apache.spark.SparkConf and org.apache.spark.api.java.* files)

Am I missing a step, or does anyone know about it ?

Thanks !

**EDIT**

Imports needed for the first example of the book :

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint;
```

I downloaded from [this link](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) :

Spark Release : 1.2.1

Package Type : Source Code

Download Type : Direct Download

(This is my first post on Stack Overflow so don't hesitate to tell me if I'm doing it wrong)

Comment: Could you please add a short code sample with the  necessary imports and a link to the spark packages you downloaded ?

Comment: I added them in the main post for better text formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look and tell you if I can reproduce your problem ! Regarding your post itself, you may want to lighten it a bit (lots of words right now :) ), indicating the error message you get if any, and post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could indicate how you compile your program (command line, maven, eclipse, ...)

Comment: Thanks ! I compile it with eclipse. The only error message I get is "The import org.apache cannot be resolved" as I can't find the right location in the downloaded sources.

Comment: Well, have you even included Spark MLlib in your project?

Comment: Maybe I was unclear but there is no such thing as an includable jar in the downloaded sources... Even the official examples rely on files that don't exist in the downloaded sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the jar you want, you have to compile the sources you downloaded with [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) (If you're not familiar with this tool, I advise you to download a pre-built version).

Once built, you will find the jar you want in `yourSparkFolder/spark-1.2.1/mllib/target`.

Please note this will only solve this specific problem. Spark mlibs has various dependencies listed [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html#Dependencies). Personnaly, I managed these by using maven in my spark project (you can find the required dependencies [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark)).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you!

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```